# I Almost am a Chicken

Tags: riddle, wordplay, rhyme, lateral-thinking, english

> I almost am a chicken,
>   Not quite a famous horse.
>   Confined to my domain,
>   I'll help you see the course.
>
> I almost am contagious,
>   Not quite a Youtube part.
>   Use a pencil when you're ready
>   And light me when you fart.

Each line is a clue.
Together they target what specific object?

---

Example:
I almost teach you something. (train)
I almost chart your progress. (track)
I'm almost around your neck. (tie)
I almost am your buttocks. (caboose)
Answer: Railroad

Comment: *"And light me when you fart."* DVL13 $\color{darkorange}{\bigstar}$ hahah :P

Comment: hmmmm, (rot 13) V org vg fgnegf jvgu n p naq puvpxra naq pbagntvbhf ersre gb gur jbeq vgfrys naq abg jung gur jbeq ersref gb.

Comment: "Golden Nugget"?

Comment: Acrostic spells out INCIINUAET -> insinuate?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Maybe it's something related to

> guns

I almost am a chicken,

> cock (male chicken, a gun part)

Not quite a famous horse.

> [Trigger](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trigger_%28horse%29)

Confined to my domain,

> range (a function's range, shooting range) OP: scope

I'll help you see the course.

> sight (eyesight, guns can have sights)

I almost am contagious,

> grip (the flu, gun handle)

Not quite a Youtube part.

> clip (videoclip, clips of ammo)

Use a pencil when you're ready

> draw (draw with a pencil, draw a gun)

And light me when you fart.

> fire (lighting a match, gunfire)

Comment: Aha! I've been thinking (and am probably right) that this question as a whole was "too broad." :)  Your overall answer is correct and, other than "domain," the individual answers are too. Just fill in the ?s.

Comment: [This should help](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/The+grip).

Comment: Kagd zmyq paqez'f dtkyq iuft "emrq" ad "omré"... paqe uf dtkyq iuft "nmdr"? :D

Comment: @user477343 Did you mean to Rot1 instead of Rot13? :)

Comment: Look at the URL of the "this should help" post.

Comment: @Chowzen nah, I made it Rot14 just for jokes, hahah, and 'cos it is completely off-topic :D

Comment: @user477343 Ymesrhay ithway affytay :)

Comment: Wait, that's not Rot... interesting...

Comment: I was intending "domain" to clue "[fpbcr](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scope_(computer_science))," but your answer is just as good.

Answer (score 7):

Ah, resolved my issue with my theory, so now it's a guess.

I almost am a chicken,

> X = (Eggs)

Not quite a famous horse.

> C = (Sea)horse

Confined to my domain,

> N = (in)

I'll help you see the course.

> I = (eye)

I almost am contagious,

> 6 = (sick)

Not quite a Youtube part.

> Q = (queue)

Use a pencil when you're ready

> Right-arrow = (write)

And light me when you fart.

> : = (colon)
>
>  You are a keyboard.

Comment: Very Entertaining, +1! Check out hint #5, though: "Each of the 8 lines describes a different **word** which has a homophone/homograph."

Comment: See Awesome Hint # 6

Answer (score 5):

Are you

> Match

I almost am a chicken,

> H**atch**

Not quite a famous horse.

> [Dan P**atch**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dan_Patch)

Confined to my domain,

> ?

I'll help you see the course.

> Path is close to the letters... (Yeah not really :p)

I almost am contagious,

> C**atch**y

Not quite a Youtube part.

> ?

Use a pencil when you're ready

> Scr**atch**

And light me when you fart.

> Match

Comment: Hmmm... If the hint was, "The object is not a rhyme," this might work.

Comment: Looking back, that comment may have sounded mean... :) I was trying to give a new hint

Comment: See Awesome Hint # 6

Answer (score 4):

Are you an,

> iPad Pro?

I am almost a chicken,

> There was this thing back when a chicken was laying eggs watching others through an ipad screen.

Not quite a famous horse.

> Hinted on the pads/ saddles of a horse- probably

Confined to my domain, I'll help you see the course.

> Both the lines hints towards a "Tablet"

I am almost contagious.

> We all know the influence Ipads have in today's world- hence the essence of the word contagious

Not quite a youtube part.

> There was an issue where people were unable to play youtube videos on ipads

Use a pencil when you're ready.

> You can buy a "Pencil" separately to use with the ipad pro when you are ready to put in that amount of cash for a pencil!

And light me when you fart.

> Well who doesn't use a bit of technology on the pooper!

Honestly, that's all the IQ I've got. LOL

Is a great riddle though!

Comment: Hello, and welcome to the **Puzzling Stack Exchange (Puzzling.SE)**. Please further explain your answer; i.e., reveal how and why the riddle suggests your answer. Thus far, your answer appears to be spam, and spam is not tolerated in the *Stack Exchange* community. If you are unwilling to improve your answer, then delete it altogether. I strongly recommend visiting the [**Help Center**](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/help) for more information, particularly [here](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: See Awesome Hint # 6

Comment: Yay, you have improved your answer! $(+1)$ :D

Answer (score 3):

Are you

> yellow?  (i know, not an object but...)

I almost am a chicken,

> yellow is associated with cowardice (or being a chicken)

Not quite a famous horse.

> not quite yellowhorse

Confined to my domain,

> domain of light?

I'll help you see the course.

> yellow lines on a racecourse

I almost am contagious,

> yellow fever is contagious

Not quite a Youtube part.

> ??

Use a pencil when you're ready

> yellow number 2 pencils

And light me when you fart.

> yellow air fresheners and candles

Comment: Sorry, no, the object in question is indeed physical. It can be touched, dropped, kicked, smelled, used as a paperweight or bookend, bought, sold, stolen, given as a wedding gift, ground up into little pieces, melted, pawned, etc. Some would say it could be eaten, but probably only once.

Comment: See Awesome Hint # 6

Comment: Might be worth putting the hints back in for future readers? I was pretty confused by the references to hints until I checked the edit history

Answer (score 3):

I am working this line by line based on the hint at homonyms. I believe the final answer or **target** is probably an acrostic of sorts, or something common between all of the words. Not sure yet.

---

Although, another thought just occurred to me; perhaps the answer itself is a homonym set in which each word is four letters long, like:

> *Fawn* like a young deer and *fawn* like a servile display of flattery.

---

*I almost am a chicken,*

> Chicken like cowardly and chicken like the bird. Could also be *hatch* as in birth from an egg and *hatch* like a door.

*Not quite a famous horse.*

> Could be *stud* like a board in a wall and *stud* like a stallion.

*Confined to my domain,*

> Could be *address* like speak to a group and *address* like a place. Could also be *yard* like three feet and *yard* like a piece of ground adjoining a house.

*I'll help you see the course.*

> Could be *journey* like traveling and *journey* like a long process of change. Could also be *trip* like traveling and *trip* like fall.

*I almost am contagious,*

> *Sick* like, well sick; and *sick* like too much of, also *sick* like excellent (informal).

*Not quite a Youtube part.*

> Could be *watch* like observe and *watch* like the timepiece.

*Use a pencil when you're ready*

> Could be *draw* like make art and *draw* like *draw* like extract.

*And light me when you fart.*

> *Match* like matchstick and *match* like a pair.

Comment: +1, closest yet (though none right :) ) I just found this interesting tidbit: "*Words That Both Sound The Same And Are Spelled The Same* are both homonyms (same sound) and homographs (same spelling). Example: lie (untruth) and lie (prone); fair (county fair), fair (reasonable)." I've added that to Hint #5.

Comment: @Chowzen so simple confusion on my part lol I’ll adjust tomorrow :)

Comment: @Chowzen So now that I am more awake lol homographs are spelled the same but sound different. Homophones are spelled differently but sound the same; and homonyms are spelled the same and sound the same but have different meanings which is your example above.

Comment: @Chowzen I've updated my answer and would love some feedback at this point. Without it I'll be stuck here lol

Comment: See Awesome Hint # 6

Answer (score 1):

1.

> Duck -- The animal is similar to a chicken, the homonym is the action to try to dodge a bullet

2.

> Secret(e) -- The most famous horse being Secretariat, a secret is not quite the full name of the horse; the homonym being secrete, and allows things to discharge some form of slime

3.

> Pen -- Slang for a prison; the homonym being the writing utensil

4.

> Map -- a map is an object that could let you plot out the path (course) you're going to take; the homonym I considered is when you represent an object with another piece of data.
>  (I am also considering "Glasses" here, since they can literally let you see something, and could also mean a set of cups)

5.

> Viral (virile) -- When a video becomes viral, it's not contagious, but it spreads rapidly and mostly uncontrolled; viral also could just be related to an actual virus; I added virile in here in case viral is still considered the same word.

6.

> Film -- while YouTube has videos it doesn't actually require film; the homonym being a thin membrane

7.

> Mark -- When you take a test, you mark your answers ; there are a lot of choices for other meanings of mark, though many of them are similar.  I'm going to go with the old German Mark, as a type of money.

8.

> Gas -- When you fart, you pass gas, which can be lit on fire; for another meaning, if you're gassed, you're exhausted.

Total???

> Since my results left me with no vowels (DSPM, VFMG), I'm going to have to assume it's somehow describing an object.  Currently, I'm at a loss.  The best I can come up with is some spy movie.

Comment: On the right track with Secretariat, but not that horse. See Awesome Hint # 6

Answer (score 1):

Partial:

Are you:

> Alcohol?

*I almost am a chicken,*

> Speckled Hen is a brand of beer.

*Not quite a famous horse.*

> Red Rum is the most famous horse I know, rum is obviously an alcoholic spirit.

Answer (score 0):

Partial

I almost am a chicken,

> chick (baby chicken) -> cheek (face?)

Not quite a famous horse.

> ??

Confined to my domain,

> range (of a function) -> range (shooting range)

I'll help you see the course.

> lead (lead the way) -> lead (chemical element Pb)

I almost am contagious,

> flu (caused by virus) -> flew (flying)

Not quite a Youtube part.

> ??

Use a pencil when you're ready

> draw (draw with a pencil) -> draw (nock, draw, loose)

And light me when you fart.

> ??

So,

> cheek, ??, range, lead, flew, ??, draw, ??
> closest thing I can think of is an arrow